# How to find the string that matches in array?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get the full string element from an array that matches multiple substrings in no particular order. If more than one match, an exception should be thrown.

```
var thisArray = [ '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/', '/and_something_else_here/'];
var thisMatch = [ 'some', 'and', 'here'];

var matchingElement = new RegExp(thisArray , thisMatch); // Not sure about this
```

What I want is for `matchineElement` to contain the string *"and_something_else_here"* after the regular expression has executed.

Comment: Why do your strings have slashes in them?

Comment: That was just copied from another example. The slashes do not matter.

Comment: Are they really going to be there, so the solution has to remove them before matching?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Sorry, I have removed the slashes from thisMatch.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vm0q0v2d/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regexp that matches a string containing all of a set of substrings looks like:

```
^(?=.*?string1)(?=.*?string2)(?=.*?string3).*$
```

So you just need to convert your `thisMatch` array into such a regular expression.

```
var regexp = new RegExp('^' + thisMatch.map(function(x) {
    return '(?=.*?' + x + ')';
}).join('') + '.*$');
```

Then you can find all the matches with:

```
var matchingElements = thisArray.filter(function(x) {
    return regexp.test(x);
});

if (matchingElements.length != 1) {
    throw new Error('Single match not found');
} else {
    matchingElement = matchingElements[0];
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/7d8rokLq/4/)

Comment: I tried to put your code example in jsFiddle, but it comes up with an error: http://jsfiddle.net/7d8rokLq/

Comment: I fixed some errors: `Regexp` should be `RegExp`, missing `)` in the call to `filter`, and `join()` needs an argument because the default is to join with comma.

Comment: no need for an extra anon: [1,2,3].filter(/./.test, /[13579]$/), /./.test() works well with map/filter already

Comment: @dandavis It took me too much effort to figure out how that convoluted expression works, I'm not going to change my answer to use it. It would be clearer if you'd used `Array.prototype.test` instead of `/./.test`, which confuses things by using a regexp that never actually gets used.

Comment: Array.prototype.test==/./.test, and i was going for comment brevity.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var thisArray = [ '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/', '/and_something_else_here/'];
var thisMatch = [ 'some', 'and', 'here'];

function matchElements(arr, arrMatch) {
    var tmpArr;
    arrMatch.forEach(function(el, i, a) {
        tmpArr = arr.filter(function(str) {
            return str.indexOf(el) !== -1;
        });
    });
    if (tmpArr.length > 1) {
        throw ("Hey, too many matches");
    } else {
        return tmpArr[0];   
    }
}

console.log(matchElements(thisArray, thisMatch));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Le53y7ee/

Explanation:

The function goes through every element in the array containing substrings and filters main array keeping only strings that match. After the loop is done the array should contain only string(s) that matched all required substrings.

Answer (score 0):

Take those slashes off of both sides of your Strings in those Arrays. Then use the `arrayMatch` function below, and loop over your indexes to get the results of `thisArray`, like:

```
function arrayMatch(yourArray, wordMatchArray){
  var ix = [], c = wordMatchArray.length;
  for(var i=0,l=yourArray.length; i<l; i++){
    var m = 0;
    for(var n=0; n<c; n++){
      if(yourArray[i].match(new RegExp(wordMatchArray[n])))m++;
      if(c === m)ix.push(i);
    }
  }
  if(!ix[0]){
    return false;
  }
  return ix;
}
var indexes = arrayMatch(thisArray, thisMatch);
for(var i=0,l=indexes.length; i<l; i++){
  var getMatch = thisArray[indexes[i]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var matchingElement = thisArray.filter(function(val, key) {
 var value = val.split(/[^a-z]/).filter(String).join(" ");
 // if `.test()` returns `true` three times at `value`
 return new RegExp(this[0]).test(value) 
        && new RegExp(this[1]).test(value) 
        && new RegExp(this[2]).test(value) 
        ? val
        : null
}.bind(thisMatch))[0].replace(/\//g,"");)
```

```js
var thisArray = [ '/something_else/', '/and_something_else/', '/and_something_else_here/'];
var thisMatch = [ 'some', 'and', 'here'];

var matchingElement = thisArray.filter(function(val, key) {
 var value = val.split(/[^a-z]/).filter(String).join(" ");
 // if `.test()` returns `true` three times at `value`
 return new RegExp(this[0]).test(value) 
        && new RegExp(this[1]).test(value) 
        && new RegExp(this[2]).test(value) 
        ? val
        : null
}.bind(thisMatch))[0].replace(/\//g,"");

document.write(matchingElement)
```